# Java8 Nested Streams write back with setter

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I´m trying to loop over two  lists, filter the nested list and write the result back into the main object with java8 features.

```
locations.forEach(location -> location.getSubList().stream()
            .filter(this::correctTestDataValue)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

So by now the sublist inside location doesnt change, which is
obvious because stream and collect do create a new list, which
is not written back into the location object.
So my question is, if there is a way to call the setSubList(...) method
of the location object and writing the new list into it.

Thx

Comment: Could you give some sample input / output that explains what the expected behavior is?

Comment: This is probably going to be messier than a for loop...

Comment: for example the solution from assylias below would produce the exact behaviour I want, but I would like to now if it is possible to do it completly with the java8 features

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a for loop:

```
for (Location location : locations) {
  List<?> newList = location.getSubList().stream()
                                         .filter(this::correctTestDataValue)
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
  location.setSubList(newList);
}
```

Or if you can remove in place:

```
for (Location location : locations) {
  location.getSubList().removeIf(x -> !correctTestDataValue(x));
}
```

Which can work as a stream:

```
locations.stream()
    .map(Location::getSublist)
    .forEach(list -> list.removeIf(x -> !correctTestDataValue(x)));
```

Comment: yes, the for loop is my solution too. But I was wondering if it wouldnt be possible with the java 8 lambda/stream features.

Comment: @Logarith, the idea of Java Streams is to keep the stream source immutable. Thanks to this it's safe to return the stream from public method which is created from your private data structure.